# Problem 12.7 in "A Probabilistic Theory of Pattern Recognition"

Tags: probability, statistics, inequality

I'm trying to understand the Problem 12.7 in the book [A Probabilistic Theory of Pattern Recognition](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4612-0711-5). This is part of the proof of Theorem 12.7.

For the sake of clarity, I'll introduce a few notations before presenting the problem:

- let $Z_1, Z_2, \ldots, Z_n, Z_1', Z_2', \ldots, Z_n'$ be iid random variables;
- for any measurable set $A$ in some class of sets $\mathcal{A}$,
  \begin{aligned}
  \nu(A) & = \mathbf{P}\left\{Z \in A\right\}, \\
  \nu_n(A) & = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^{n} I_{\left\{Z_i \in A\right\}}, \\
  \nu_n'(A) & = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^{n} I_{\left\{Z_i' \in A\right\}}.
  \end{aligned}

The problem, as in the book, is presented below.

---

PROBLEM 12.7. Prove that
$$
\mathbf{P}\left\{\sup _{A: v_n(A)=0}\left|v_n(A)-v(A)\right|>\epsilon\right\} \leq 2 \mathbf{P}\left\{\sup _{A: v_n(A)=0}\left|v_n(A)-v_n^{\prime}(A)\right|>\frac{\epsilon}{2}\right\}
$$
holds if $n \epsilon>2$. This inequality is needed to complete the proof of Theorem 12.7. HINT: Proceed as in the proof of Theorem 12.5. Introduce $A^*$ with $v_n\left(A^*\right)=0$ and justify the validity of the steps of the following chain of inequalities:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbf{P} & \left\{\sup _{A: v_n(A)=0}\left|v_n(A)-v_n^{\prime}(A)\right|>\epsilon / 2\right\} \\
& \geq \mathbf{E}\left\{I_{\left\{v\left(A^*\right)>\epsilon\right\}} \mathbf{P}\left\{v_n^{\prime}\left(A^*\right) \geq \frac{\epsilon}{2} \mid Z_1, \ldots, Z_n\right\}\right\} \\
& \geq \mathbf{P}\left\{B(n, \epsilon)>\frac{n \epsilon}{2}\right\} \mathbf{P}\left\{\left|v_n\left(A^*\right)-v\left(A^*\right)\right|>\epsilon\right\},
\end{aligned}
$$
where $B(n, \epsilon)$ is a binomial random variable with parameters $n$ and $\epsilon$. Finish the proof by showing that the probability on the right-hand side is greater than or equal to $1 / 2$ if $n \epsilon>2$. (Under the slightly more restrictive condition $n \epsilon>8$, this follows from Chebyshev's inequality.)

---

Based on the hint above, and the proof of Theorem 12.4 (which is related to Theorem 12.5), I started my solution:

Let $A^* \in \mathcal{A}$ be a set for which $$\nu\left(A^*\right)>\varepsilon \text{ and } \nu_n\left(A^*\right)=0.$$ If such a set does not exist, let $A^*$ be a fixed set that guarantees $\nu_n\left(A^*\right)=0$. Then,
\begin{aligned}
\mathbf{P}&\left(\sup _{A: \nu_n(A)= 0} \left|\nu_n(A)-\nu_n^{\prime}(A)\right|>\varepsilon / 2\right) \\
& \geq \mathbf{P}\left(\left|\nu_n\left(A^*\right)-\nu_n^{\prime}\left(A^*\right)\right|>\varepsilon / 2\right)=\mathbf{P}\left(\nu_n^{\prime}(A^*) >\varepsilon / 2\right) \\
& \geq \mathbf{P}\left(\nu\left(A^*\right)>\varepsilon,\nu_n^{\prime}\left(A^*\right)>\varepsilon / 2\right) \\
& =E\left\{I_{\left\{v\left(A^{*}\right)>\varepsilon\right\}} \mathbf{P}\left[v_n^{\prime}\left(A^*\right)>\varepsilon/2 \mid Z_1, \ldots, Z_n\right]\right\} \\
& \stackrel{(* *)}{=} \mathbf{P}\left[\nu_n^{\prime}\left(A^*\right)>\varepsilon / 2\right] E\left[I_{\left\{\nu\left(A^*\right)>\varepsilon\right\}}\right] \\
& =\mathbf{P}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n I_{\left\{Z_i^{\prime} \in A^*\right\}}> n \varepsilon / 2\right) \mathbf{P}\left(\nu\left(A^*\right)>\varepsilon\right) \\
&\equiv \mathbf{P}\left(B(n, \nu(A^*))> n \varepsilon / 2\right) \mathbf{P}\left(\left|\nu_n(A^*) - \nu\left(A^*\right)\right|>\varepsilon\right),
\end{aligned}
where in $(* *)$ I used the fact that $Z_i$s and $Z_i'$s are independent.

Am I doing something wrong?

---

More specifically, my questions are:

- I don't know how they came to a $B(n, \epsilon)$ in the last inequality of the HINT.
- Looking at other proofs in the book (e.g. Theorem 12.4), I think it is necessary to show that, if $n\varepsilon > 2$, then $\mathbf{P}\left\{B(n, \epsilon)>\frac{n \epsilon}{2}\right\} \geq \frac{1}{2}$. The result makes sense, but don't know to show this.
- Furthermore, I don't know how to use Chebyshev's inequality, since it provides upper bounds for this kind of probability and we need a lower bound.
- Finally, based on my solution, I think that I can do $\mathbf{P}\left(B(n, \nu(A^*))> n \varepsilon / 2\right) \geq \mathbf{P}\left(B(n, \varepsilon)> n \varepsilon / 2\right)$, but I don't know how to show this either.

---

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding the comment about Chebychev: the probability of the complement can be bounded by $P(B(n, \epsilon) \le n\epsilon / 2) \le P(|B(n, \epsilon) - n\epsilon| \ge n\epsilon / 2) \le \frac{n\epsilon(1-\epsilon)}{n^2\epsilon^2 / 4} \le \frac{4}{n\epsilon} < \frac{1}{2}$ if $n\epsilon > 8$.

For a sharper argument, note that any median $m$ of $B(n,\epsilon)$ (i.e. [$m$ satisfies $P(B(n,\epsilon) \le m) \ge 1/2$ and $P(B(n,\epsilon) < m)< 1/2$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median#Probability_distributions)) is [at least $\lfloor n\epsilon \rfloor$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Median). If $n\epsilon > 2$, then $n\epsilon/2 < \lfloor n\epsilon \rfloor$, so $P(B(n,\epsilon) \le n\epsilon/2) < 1/2$.

---

For your other question: $I_{\{Z'_i \in A^*\}}$ is Bernoulli with mean $\nu(A^*)$, not $\nu'_n(A^*)$. It remains to show that the assumption $\nu(A^*) > \epsilon$ implies $P(B(n,\nu(A^*)) > n\epsilon/2) \ge P(B(n, \epsilon) > n\epsilon/2)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It helped a lot. I fixed the binomial probability. In case somebody else is interested, I found how to show that $B(n, \nu(A^*))$ dominates $B(n, \varepsilon)$, if $\nu(A^*) > \varepsilon$. The result is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2139315/how-to-show-a-binomial-random-variable-dominates-another-binomial-random-variabl), in an answer by @drhab.

Comment: Are you sure the result using Hoeffding's inequality is correct? It seems that $e^{-2/n} < 1/2$ only if $n < 2/\log 2 < 3$. If I'm not doing anything wrong, this assumption is too restrictive.

Comment: @michelcias You are right, my usage of Hoeffding was not tight enough to get the desired bound. I have replaced it with a simpler argument.

Comment: @michelcias So everything is ok now, right?

Comment: I think so. Thanks!

Comment: @michelcias The definition of median you suggested in your edit was not quite right, so I added the full definition and a link.

Comment: Thanks. I understood and agree with you.